# payload changing to com.mulesoft.weave.reader.DefaultSeekableStream (Mule 3)

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

Payload in muleflow is getting converted in com.mulesoft.weave.reader.DefaultSeekableStream from org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream. I am not sure why and due to this the subsequent activities (dw transformer) is failed. Anyone have any idea what could be the reason and how to overcome this.

The payload is pretty simple and I am trying to use two transformation activity, In first activity I parse the payload and create a flowVariable and in second transformation is to add values in payload. However, after first transformation the payload is changed to DefaultSeekableStream.

[image: Before transformation]

[image: After transformation]

Thanks,
Abhi

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Hi! The implementation class Mule uses to manage the stream should not be an issue. Can you post the concrete error or the stack of the error you are getting? Also please confirm if this is Mule 4.

Comment: @JorgeGarcia Thanks mate, I have added error message as well and this is Mule 3.

Comment: Great. I have the feeling that this has to do with trying to read the stream more than once. Also debugging can make it behave differently than just running it. As a quick workaround, you can try to convert the payload into java as a first step and then work with that object to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I manage to solve it to convert the payload back to java stream. Thanks.